# Register remote notifications ios10 and catch the apn token

Tags: ios10

Could anybody explain to me how to register for remote push notification and catch the token, using the new UserNotification framework provided by iOS10 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register to notifications like you're already doing from iOS 8 (it's one of the few API for notifications that hasn't changed).

First, in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method of the AppDelegate, request the authorization for your app:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization([.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
    //here you can check the correct authorization    
}
```

This will show the usual "Application would like to send you notifications" alert. The main improvement of the new `requestAuthorization` method is that you can manage the behaviour of tapping on Allow / Don't Allow buttons directly in the closures.

Next, register for remote notifications with the `registerForRemoteNotifications` method of `UIApplication` available from iOS 8:

```
UIApplication.shared().registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

...and finally manage the registration with your notifications server (like Amazon, OneSignal, etc...)

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    //if you need the token as a string, do this:
    let tokenString = String(data: deviceToken, encoding: .utf8)

    //call the notifications server for sending the device token
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Application failed to register for remote notifications")
}
```

[Reference](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/49437)

Answer (score 2):

With Objective-C method:

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        [self registerForRemoteNotification];
        . . .
    }


    - (void)registerForRemoteNotification {
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 10.0) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter *uncenter = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
            [uncenter setDelegate:self];
            [uncenter requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionAlert+UNAuthorizationOptionBadge+UNAuthorizationOptionSound)
                                    completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
                                        NSLog(@"%@" , granted ? @"success to request authorization." : @"failed to request authorization .");
                                    }];
            [uncenter getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:^(UNNotificationSettings * _Nonnull settings) {
                NSLog(@"%s\nline:%@\n-----\n%@\n\n", __func__, @(__LINE__), settings);
                if (settings.authorizationStatus == UNAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
                    //TODO:
                } else if (settings.authorizationStatus == UNAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
                    //TODO:
                } else if (settings.authorizationStatus == UNAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
                    //TODO:
                }
            }];
        }
    #pragma clang diagnostic push
    #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 8.0) {
            UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                           UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                           UIUserNotificationTypeSound;
            UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        } else {
            UIRemoteNotificationType types = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                             UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                             UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:types];
        }
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
    }
```

Here is a demo: [iOS10AdaptationTips](https://github.com/ChenYilong/iOS10AdaptationTips/stargazers).