# didReceiveLocalNotification not getting called after using UNUserNotificationCenter

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification, usernotifications

I am scheduling local notifications. It works in iOS 9.x but since iOS 10

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

doesn't get called when app is running on iOS 10.

I know that iOS has introduced new `UserNotifications` framework but that shouldn't stop working iOS 9 APIs.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UILocalNotification is deprecated in iOS10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938771/uilocalnotification-is-deprecated-in-ios10)

Comment: @pedrouan: I have already tried the solution given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938771/uilocalnotification-is-deprecated-in-ios10. But it's not working.

Comment: I have the same problem with didReceiveLocalNotification stopped firing in iOS 10.0 and 10.1 GA.  Looks like it's not just deprecated, it's not supported anymore unfortunately.

Answer (score 7):

As you know, iOS 10 introduced the `UNUserNotifications` framework to handle both local and remote notifications. Using this framework, you can set a delegate to detect when a notification is presented or tapped.

```
[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = yourDelegate;
```

...

```
// In your delegate ...

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {

    // Notification arrived while the app was in foreground

    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
    // This argument will make the notification appear in foreground
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {

    // Notification was tapped.

    completionHandler();
}
```

Now, if you still want to use the old (deprecated) `application:didReceiveLocalNotification` and `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler`, the solution is simple: just **don't set any delegate** to `UNUserNotificationCenter`.

Note that silent remote notifications (those which contain the `content-available` key and no `alert`, `sound`, or `badge`) are always handled by `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler`, even if you have set the delegate.

Comment: I will give a try and let you know if this works or not. Thank you.