# how to generate local notification in ios 10 when your app in forground? When your app in forground then it's not work

Tags: ios, objective-c

this following step i do in my app

in my **appdelegate**

```
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    UNUserNotificationCenter* center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
      center.delegate = (id)self;

    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionSound)
                          completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {


                              // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
                          }];







    return YES;
}
```

and in my **viewcontroller** the code for generate local notification

```
-(IBAction)btnclicked:(id)sender 
{
    UNMutableNotificationContent* content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
    content.title = @"gg";
     content.subtitle = @"ggg";
    content.body = @"hhh";
    content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];

    // Deliver the notification in five seconds.
    UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger* trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger
                                                  triggerWithTimeInterval:5 repeats:NO];
    UNNotificationRequest* request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"2"
                                                                          content:content trigger:trigger
                                      ];

    // Schedule the notification.
    UNUserNotificationCenter* center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"hii");
    }];





}
```

Now When my app in **foreground** Notification not generating.

in ios 9 i use

```
 UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.soundName = @"Default";
    localNotification.alertBody = @"my notification;)";
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
    localNotification.category = @"Email";
    localNotification.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitDay;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

this code work in ios 9 but in ios 10 UILocalNotification is deprecate.

so how to generate local notification in ios 10 when your app in foreground ?

Comment: I can post you the solution in swift it that is oke ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UILocalNotification is deprecated in iOS10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938771/uilocalnotification-is-deprecated-in-ios10)

Comment: @Mingebag it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it with `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` in iOS10

> iOS 10 adds the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` protocol for handling notifications while your app is in the foreground.

[Hope this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852870/displaying-a-stock-ios-notification-banner-when-your-app-is-open-and-in-the-fore#37844312)

Comment: i am already using User Notifications framework . my question is how to generate local notification in ios 10 when your app in foreground ?

Answer (score -1):

For displaying banner message while app is in foreground, use the following method.

iOS 10, Swift 3 :

// This method will be called when app received push notifications in foreground

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) 
{
    completionHandler(
       [UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert,
        UNNotificationPresentationOptions.sound,
        UNNotificationPresentationOptions.badge])
}
```

Comment: willPresent notification: work in local notification ?