# Schedule repeat alarm with end date

Tags: ios

I am using following code to trigger repeat alarm with end date.

```
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.month,.day,.hour,.minute], from: date, to: TODate)
```

After this code I have used notification for trigger. But this code is not working for triggering notifications.

But following code (only from date) works perfectly.

```
let components = calendar.dateComponents(in: .current, from: date).
```

How can I schedule a repeat alarm with end date?

Comment: check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938771/uilocalnotification-is-deprecated-in-ios10

Comment: @nferocious76 Hi, I need to schedule with from date and to date, is it possible?

Comment: have you tried creating 2 components with current date and 'to date' and load it? I haven't really dig deeper to this API so I can't give you an exact answer but some hints.