# UILocalNotification receiving function deprecated in iOS10 (Swift 3.0)

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, delegates, uilocalnotification

I was wondering which delegate function, we should use in swift 3.0 instead of :

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

for handling notifications, when received as this delegate function is deprecated. I checked this link as well:
[UILocalNotification is deprecated in iOS10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938771/uilocalnotification-is-deprecated-in-ios10) but didn't find receiving delegate.
If I Use same delegate function, the delegate isn't is getting called.

Thanks.

Comment: use UNUserNotificationCenter

Comment: So, will it remain same ?

Comment: Go through this -> https://useyourloaf.com/blog/local-notifications-with-ios-10/

Comment: UILocalNotification is *not* UNUserNotification. [userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649501-usernotificationcenter) should work for iOS 10 as mentioned in its documentation (iOS 10.0+).

Comment: @dahiya_boy It helped. Thank you for saving my time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding with your case [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalnotification) is deprecated so far (as you already mentioned "[UILocalNotification is deprecated in iOS10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938771/uilocalnotification-is-deprecated-in-ios10)" in your question) and that's what are you asking about:

> **UILocalNotification** receiving function deprecated in iOS10 (Swift 3.0)

But method: [`userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649501-usernotificationcenter) has *nothing* to do with `UILocalNotification`, instead, it is related to the [UserNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications) Framework, which *does* supports iOS 10 -as mentioned in its documentation-:

[image]

So basically, you should go UserNotification instead of -deprecated- UILocalNotification, therefore:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

should work as expected with iOS 10.

Comment: Ok. Then, I think I have to check, why it isn't working. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Glad to help. Please don't hesitate to ask in case of facing any issue...

Comment: Sure. Thank you :)